# How to pass parameters to a custom kernel function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, svm

I'm using the [fitcsvm](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html?refresh=true) method of Matlab for training a SVM classifier. Using the name-value pair 'KernelFunction', 'myKernel' it is possible to provide a custom kernel implementation. The kernel must be defined in a .m file in the following way `function G = kernel(U,V)`.

The only way I see for passing parameters to the kernel (like gamma for the Gaussian kernel) is to use global variables which is not so nice in the context of parallel execution.

Is there another possibility for passing parameters to the kernel?

Comment: This [post](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/160726-how-can-i-use-fitcsvm-and-pass-parameters-to-a-custom-kernel) has a good answer. In short - yes, you're stuck with having to use a global variable, but you can create a proxy function as described there to make your life easier. Alternatively, consider using [LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/)

Comment: @nirvana-msu Does the global variable hold only for the Matlab session (instance) or does it hold for all sessions?

Comment: Only for the current instance. You'd need to store preferences on disk and load them, to persist across Matlab sessions.